# Should the function be wrapped to async

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am dealing with some codebase and there was a discussion between me and a colleague whether to put `async` before the function name in this case. I'd say yes, because we have a Promise inside, but might be wrong here. Any advice?

```
return {
    **async ???** loadSmthForFilter: function (diseases) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.get('/api/bla', { diseases })
          .done(resolve)
          .fail(reject);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you don't *need* to. It depends if you want to use the `await` operator (add the `async` keyword) or use the `then` function chaining (No need to add it).

If you choose to you have it in the wrong place

```
return {
  loadSmthForFilter: async function (diseases) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.get('/api/bla', { diseases })
      .done(resolve)
      .fail(reject);
   });
}
```

BTW you should just return `$.get` directly as that is a promise, no need to wrap it in another promise. See: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: Sorry, that's correct, put it in the wrong place. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You don't NEED to use async with this function. The function return a Promise but don't await one. But, I usually put async for a function that return a promise to await the output.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` keyword can be very useful when needed, but it adds some extra overhead to the function call because it internally wraps a try/catch around the function body and it handles the return value differently and it creates a promise.

So, I use `async` only when needed and that's when I want to use `await` inside the function or very occasionally, when I want to take advantage of the automatic try/catch wrapping and I'm using asynchronous operations of some kind.

In your case, none of these situations seem to apply, so I'd remove the promise anti-pattern (manually wrapping a promise in another), return the promise that `$.get()` already returns and do this:

```
return {
    loadSmthForFilter: function (diseases) {
        return $.get('/api/bla', { diseases });
    }
};
```